# How to fix cannot set rows in Mismatched columns error, in my web scraping code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests #importing beautifulsoup and requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html') #storing beautiful soup in soup variable

print(soup) # to see what it displays

soup.find('table') # finding every tag labelled table

soup.find('table', class_ = 'wikitable sortable') # trying to specify tables

table = soup.find_all('table')[0] # this is the one I want

print(table) # to see what it displays

table.find_all('th') # find all the th (column headings) tags in the table.

world_titles = table.find_all('th') # so i can just type world_titles instead of table.find_all('th') all the time

world_table_titles = [title.text.strip() for title in world_titles] # removing /n and making data clean

print(world_table_titles) # seeing what it displays

import pandas as pd # importing pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = world_table_titles) # making a dataframe

df

column_data = table.find_all('tr') # finding rows within my table

for row in column_data[2:]: # [2:] because the first two just displayed []
    row_data = row.find_all('td')
    individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data] #clean version of row_data
    
    length = len(df)  
    df.loc[length] = individual_row_data
    print(individual_row_data)
```

[image: image of the error I got]

I was trying to scrape the table from a wikipedia site, then got this error. What have I done wrong? and how can I fix it?

I tried to find solutions on youtube and online but found no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could get your dataframe with `pandas.read_html()` and can make adjustments on it:

```
import pandas as pd

#read in the first table
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue')[0]

# clean the column headers
df.columns = [' '.join(e for e in set(c) if not 'Unnamed' in e) for c in df.columns]

# check the result
df
```

---

However if you wanna go with `beautifulsoup` directly - Check your selection of `world_titles` the `ResultSet` is much longer as you might think. Following is much closer to your expectation:

```
world_titles = table.tr.find_all('th')
```

But you will run into another issue, so there are columns without any text, that will lead to lists with different length. So check out:

```
...
world_titles = table.tr.find_all('th')
world_table_titles = [title.text.strip() for title in world_titles]     

column_data = table.find_all('tr')

data = []

for row in column_data[2:]: # [2:] because the first two just displayed []
    row_data = row.find_all('td')
    data.append([data.text.strip() for data in row_data])

pd.DataFrame(data,columns=world_table_titles[1:])
```

Comment: thanks. could you explain "df.columns = [' '.join(e for e in set(c) if not 'Unnamed' in e) for c in df.columns]"  so I'll know what to do when I web scrape from a different site.

Comment: It iterate the columns, removes dublicated lables from indexes with the `set()` and is joining the others.

Comment: Is there any specific benefit to using BeautifulSoup? pd.read_html seems so much more easier, whats the benefit and drawback of each technique?

Comment: It always depends on what goal you want to achieve. `pandas.read_html()` uses `beautifulsoup` under the hood and is probably the method of choice for scraping tables in standard cases. It deviates from the standard when it comes to dealing with special features or scraping non-textual content.